# Ruby on rails - routes rb -Missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm completely new to coding and am trying to follow an online guide for ruby on rails. There's a folder titled routes.rb it only contains:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
There is much more code in that folder on the guide I'm following, but is all missing on mine. Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `routes.rb` is a file/document, not a folder, however not knowing how you created your project or even what guide you're following it's virtually impossible to help you further I'm afraid.

Comment: this is the guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPy0GQJLZUM&t=640s what I am talking about begins at 10:10

Comment: Yes, this is an older version of Rails he's working with there, all the code in `routes.rb` is commented out there so no worries if you don't see it in your project.

Comment: https://www.railstutorial.org/ if you want to learn Rails this is the best tutorial IMO, it is not free but you get what you pay for